# Looping through a tree to get branch or leaf

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, tree

This is my solution to a problem from MIT's 6.034 Artificial Intelligence course (see the heading **Tree reference** on [6.034 Artificial Intelligence, Lab 0](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-034-artificial-intelligence-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_034F10_lab0.pdf)). Can you please help me improve my solution (keep in mind I am a beginner with no formal education in Computer Science)? *To be clear, I am NOT taking this for school credit, this is an old class from 2010 available through MIT OpenCourseWare. [SOURCE](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-034-artificial-intelligence-fall-2010/)*

> Your job is to write a procedure that is analogous to list
>    referencing, but for trees. This "tree_ref" procedure will take a tree
>    and an index, and return the part of the tree (a leaf or a subtree) at
>    that index. For trees, indices will have to be lists of integers.
>    Consider the tree in Figure 1, represented by this Python tuple: `(((1, 2), 3), (4, (5, 6)), 7, (8, 9, 10))`
>
> To select the element 9 out of it,
>    we’d normally need to do something like `tree[3][1]`. Instead, we’d
>    prefer to do `tree_ref(tree, (3, 1))` (note that we’re using zero-based
>    indexing, as in list-ref, and that the indices come in top-down order;
>    so an index of (3, 1) means you should take the fourth branch of the
>    main tree, and then the second branch of that subtree). As another
>    example, the element 6 could be selected by `tree_ref(tree, (1, 1, 1))`.
>
> Note that it’s okay for the result to be a subtree, rather than a
>    leaf. So `tree_ref(tree, (0,))` should return `((1, 2), 3)`.

My Solution:

```
def tree_ref(tree, index):
  try:
    index = list(index)
    if not isinstance(tree, tuple) or len(index) == 0:
      return tree
    else:
      return tree_ref(tree[index[0]], index[1:])
  except IndexError:
    return "INPUT OUT OF RANGE"
```

Comment: Voting to leave open because there looks to be plenty of context for me, although figuring out sample inputs took me a second

Answer (score 1):

all in all this code does what it needs to do, but czan be improved in some small points

## Exception

Instead of the `try-except` clause, just let the exception bubble up to the caller if he passes a wrong index. returning a string in this case is almost never the correct way to treat it. Now the caller has to check each response he gets and compare it to  `"INPUT OUT OF RANGE"`. Even returning None would be better than this errorstring

## list

`index = list(index)` is useless. `tuple`s can be sliced too, and you can get the length of them

## code

The algorithm becomes very simple. It raises a `TypeError` or `IndexError` if the caller passes in something illegal, but that's his responsibility

```
def tree_ref_recursion(tree, index):
    if index:
        return tree_ref_recursion(tree[index[0]], index[1:])
    else:
        return tree
```

The `if index:` just checks whether index is a non-empty tuple. There is no need to check for the type of `tree`. If this is no more tuple, and there is still an index, the caller passed in an illegal tree or index.

## recursion

This was a recursive method. Because of the recursion, you need to check the `index`. You can also use a loop:

```
def tree_ref(tree, index):
    for idx in index:
        tree = tree[idx]
    return tree
```